# Zabbix with tiles dashboard for displaying problems

Tags: grafana, dashboard, zabbix

We are using Zabbix 5.0.2 in our company with hundreds of hosts to monitor. I am trying to find dashboard for Zabbix that will display kind of grid/tiles with all monitored items. When problem appears, it will move item to the top of screen marked red, rest of monitored items should stay below with green color.

Dashboard can be directly in Zabbix or Grafana Based. "Standard" Problems Zabbix dashboard my superiors does not like at all.

Any ideas, what dashboard to use, please?

Thank you

Wil

It should look something like this

https://xivo-solutions-blog.gitlab.io/2018/07/23/monitoring-over-one-year/status_panels.png

Comment: Why you don't use Grafana panel which will fit your needs. There is a lot of panels - https://grafana.com/grafana/plugins?type=panel. Mentioned dashboard uses https://grafana.com/grafana/plugins/vonage-status-panel

Comment: Thank you, @JanGaraj, sounds like way to go! I wil dig deeper into it